# Problems with repeat use of while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to make it so that I could enter as many commands into this program as I want before I tell it to stop working. Currently, I could type in lastname______ and everyone with that last name would appear, but then I could type in firstname______ and program would not do anything. It is still running, but won't accept anymore commands. I want it to run until I say "end"

```
while(!command.equals("end"))
        {
            if(command.equals("printall"))
                prall(st, count);
            else
            if (command.equals("firstname"))
            {    
                String parameter = scan.next();
                prFname(st,count,parameter);
            }
            else
            if(command.equals("lastname"))
            {
                String parameter = scan.next();
                prLname(st,count,parameter);
            }
            else 
            if(command.equals("interval"))
            {
                int interval1=scan.nextInt();
                int interval2=scan.nextInt();
                prInterval(st,count,interval1,interval2);
            }
            else
            if(command.equals("end"))
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be cool to actually read a new command, i.e. assigning `command` to a newly read input? You never do that and only check the first command over and over again.

Comment: What does `prFname(st,count,parameter);`do? Problem may lie there. By the way, since you'll jump out of the while loop if ```command.equals("end")``` it can be ```while(true)``` instead of ```while(!command.equals("end"))```

Comment: Your code is not complete so it is hard to understand and I don't see a clear question, more of a request.

Answer (score 2):

```
            ...
        }
        else
        if(command.equals("end"))
            break;
    }
```

Firstly, the last three lines are redundant because the loop would end anyway. I think, you just need to read a next command at the end of the loop, like this:

```
            ...
        }

        command = scan.next();
    }
```

...or whatever you use to read commands.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it seems to me like the value `command` never changes inside of the loop. Alternatively, the functions you call might not be terminating for whatever reason.